# Вопросы по UNet

Tags: unity3d, сеть

Я работал с Unet Hlapi и даже написал небольшой учебный проект с созданием, уничтожением и синхронизацией объектов. И у меня возникли некоторые вопросы, ответы на которые я в документации не нашел.

1. Какая функция вызывается при создании сервера?
2. Возможно ли в рамках UNet Hlapi реализовать клиентское предсказание. И если да, то как?
3. Возможно ли совместить интерполяцию с экстраполяцией (оная насколько я понимаю делается если в компоненте NetworkTransform установить sendRate 0). И может ли в этом помочь плагин Smooth Sync?
4. Разумно ли вообще использовать Hlapi в боевом проекте или нужно пользоваться транспортным протоколом?
5. Можете ли вы посоветовать какую-нибудь дополнительную литературу (кроме официальной документации) по работе с сетью в Unity?